# Display Description from Array using id

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, couchbase

I have the following Struct

```
manufacturers = [
{id: 1, name: 'Apple'},
{id: 2, name: 'HP'},
{id: 3, name: 'Microsoft'},
]
```

and

```
product.manufacturerId = 2;
```

Now i use the following to display the Manufacturer

```
<p ng-repeat="m in manufacturers  | filter: {id: product.manufacturerId}">{{m.name}}</p>
```

I find this way a littlebit complicated. Isn't there an easier way?

I'm using Couchbase, so I cannot make a SQL JOIN. It needs to be joined with Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `indexOf()` to get the corresponding item:

```
$scope.itemToShow = manufacturers.indexOf(product.manufacturerId);
```

then:

```
<p>{{itemToShow.name}}</p>
```

You just need to start your indexes at 0 instead of 1.

Comment: This would work with an array, but the id is NOT guaranteed to be the array position and it must be matched with the ID.

Comment: In that case, unfortunately the best way is going to be using a for loop to search for the matching item. The [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#find) _.find() method would be a good option also.